# There is a way to use ngx-translate in angular library and in root project at the same time?

Tags: angular, ngx-translate, angular-library

I have angular library with a component that uses ngx-translate for translation:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
       TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
              provide: TranslateLoader,
              useClass: WebpackTranslateLoader,
              deps: [HttpClient],
            },
            isolate: true
          }),
    ],
    ...
})
export class LibraryModule {
    ...
}
```

If I use this library in a simple project - it works as expected.
But if I use it in a project with its own ngx-translate configuration:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useClass: WebpackTranslateLoader,
        deps: [HttpClient],


       },
        }),
      ],
...
```

Then project translations don't work. Translations are taken from the shared library. 
If I don't use the library, it works as expected.

I have tried to use TranslateModule.forChild in library module and obtained this error:
AppComponent.html:1 ERROR NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[TranslateService -> TranslateStore]:

I use:

```
"@angular/core": "^9.1.4",
"@ngx-translate/core": "^12.1.2",
"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Force assignment in component root constructor solve this problem.

```
this._translateService.currentLoader = new WebpackTranslateLoader();
```

But child library translation is missing. It's problem solved by merging translations manually:

```
getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<any> {
    const result = forkJoin(
      [
        from(<rootTranslation>),
        new ChildLibraryTranslateLoader().getTranslation(lang)]
      ).pipe(map(translations => {
        return { ...translations[0], ...translations[1] };
    }));

    return result;
```